# Load twitter widget from ajax-loaded html?

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter

I'm trying to use a pretty standard twitter search widget, straight from the twitter site:

```
<script src="http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js"></script>
<script>
new TWTR.Widget({
  version: 2,
  type: 'search',
  search: '$AAPL',
  interval: 6000,
  title: 'AAPL',
  subject: '',
  width: 250,
  height: 300,
  theme: {
    shell: {
      background: '#8ec1da',
      color: '#ffffff'
    },
    tweets: {
      background: '#ffffff',
      color: '#444444',
      links: '#1985b5'
    }
  },
  features: {
    scrollbar: false,
    loop: true,
    live: true,
    hashtags: true,
    timestamp: true,
    avatars: true,
    toptweets: true,
    behavior: 'default'
  }
}).render().start();
</script>
```

And it's getting loaded like so:

```
$(".linktosymbol").bind("ajax:success", function(event, data, status, xhr) {
    $(".symboldetails").html("");
    var target = $("#" + $(this).attr('data-target'));
    target.html(data);
});
```

It never appears though, it seems to just blank the screen and go on loading forever.  Ideas?

Comment: did you try to read the params "data", "status", and "xhr", what are they telling. If you use chrome, you can put them into console. console.log(data);console.log(status);console.log(xhr);

Comment: Yeah, those are all ok.  It returns the HTML just fine - it's when it runs the twitter javascript that things go all haywire.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Had the same issue. The problem is that the Twitter JS creates the markup using `document.write`, which only works while the document is being generated. Otherwise it will create a new document.

Tip: While debugging, it's easier to use the original code at `http://twitter.com/javascripts/widgets/widget.js`.

```
<div id="twtr-widget"></div>
<script src="http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js"></script>
<script>
new TWTR.Widget({
  version: 2,
  type: 'profile',
  rpp: 4,
  interval: 6000,
  width: 500,
  height: 300,
  id: 'twtr-widget',
  theme: {
    shell: {
      background: '#333333',
      color: '#ffffff'
    },
    tweets: {
      background: '#000000',
      color: '#ffffff',
      links: '#4aed05'
    }
  },
  features: {
    scrollbar: false,
    loop: false,
    live: false,
    hashtags: true,
    timestamp: true,
    avatars: false,
    behavior: 'all'
  }
}).render().setUser('Znarkus').start();
</script>
```

That is my solution. Add the `id` parameter, and Twitter will add the markup to the element with that id (that's what the top `div` is for).

Note: I had problems with the minified version of their script, so I used `http://twitter.com/javascripts/widgets/widget.js` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#Twitter').click(function (e) {
  $.getScript
    (
      "http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js",
      function () {
         makeTwitterWidget();
       }
     ); 
});

function makeTwitterWidget() {
new TWTR.Widget
    (
        {
            version: 2,
            type: 'profile',
            rpp: 3,
            interval: 3000,
            width: 'auto',
            height: 300,
            id: 'twtr-widget', // id of DIV
            theme:
        {
            shell:
                {
                    background: '#ff0000',
                    color: '#ffffff'
                },
            tweets:
                {
                    background: '#ffffff',
                    color: '#000000',
                    links: '#ff0000'
                }
        },
            features:
            {
                scrollbar: false,
                loop: true,
                live: true,
                hashtags: true,
                timestamp: true,
                avatars: false,
                behavior: 'default'
            }
        }
    ).render().setUser('sohelelite').start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js"></script>
<script>
new TWTR.Widget({
  version: 2,
  type: 'profile',
  rpp: 4,
  interval: 6000,
  width: 250,
  height: 300,
  theme: {
    shell: {
      background: '#333333',
      color: '#ffffff'
    },
    tweets: {
      background: '#000000',
      color: '#ffffff',
      links: '#4aed05'
    }
  },
  features: {
    scrollbar: true,
    loop: false,
    live: true,
    hashtags: true,
    timestamp: true,
    avatars: true,
    behavior: 'all'
  }
}).render().setUser('roby_jazz').start();
</script>
```

Comment: It's important to explain your answer even though your answer might be absolutely correct!